# Way to track changes done to Process Templates\WIT in TFS

Tags: tfs, workitem

Is there a way to track the changes done to Process Templates or Workitem Types in TFS. Something like Logs\History etc? If so please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I did not see a change history for process template. But you can use (git or tfvc) version control:

1. Download your process template and add it to version control. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/guidance/manage-process-templates
2. Add a process template to version control.
3. Edit needed work item types and over objects through version control. Commit (or checking) new changes.
4. Update changed work item types with **witadmin importwitd** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits
5. Upload updated process template from version control for new projects: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/guidance/manage-process-templates